What index types are there other than secondary index in MySQL?
According to 17.6.2.1 Clustered and Secondary Indexes,

Indexes other than the clustered index are known as secondary indexes

This means there are only 2 types of indexes: clustered and secondary.

However, 15.1.20.9 Secondary Indexes and Generated Columns says

InnoDB supports secondary indexes on virtual generated columns. Other index types are not supported.

The plural form "other index type s" implies there are at least 3 index types (secondary + something + something).

Which is correct?
If the latter is correct, what are the other types of indexes specifically other than the secondary index?

"The plural form "other index type s" implies there are at least 3 index types" - No, you're just reading too deeply into it. What it means is that you cannot use a virtual (i.e. non-materialized - aka non-persisted generated) column in a clustered index. This is mentioned in the 4th paragraph down.

@Dai I don't understand why you think so... I don't think The plural form "other index type s" implies there are at least 3 index types is my personal subjective opinion (i.e. reading too deaply); it's the objective fact (known English syntax).

Secondary indexes may be regular, functional and multi-valued. Example: https://dbfiddle.uk/R_ESFYV0

@ynn MySQL is developed by people in Sweden - it's not an anglophone country nor company - so that's why it's unwise to make big inferences from minor grammar or syntax quirks in their documentation (...granted, now they're owned by Oracle now, and Oracle are reknown for not speaking English either, but instead software license legalease).

@Dai Thank you. I should understand it just as a documentation bug (rather than sticking to reading it literally).

@ynn I do think your question is valid though - so here, have an upvote ➕

The only other index types are SPATIAL and FULLTEXT.
You can't create these types of indexes on generated columns.
mysql> create table mytable (id serial primary key, t text, t2 text as (substring(t, 1024)));

mysql> create fulltext index i on mytable(t2);
ERROR 3106 (HY000): 'Fulltext index on virtual generated column' is not supported for generated columns.

mysql> create table mytable (id serial primary key, p point as (point(1,2)));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> create spatial index i on mytable(p);
ERROR 3106 (HY000): 'Spatial index on virtual generated column' is not supported for generated columns.


Thank you. So Indexes other than the clustered index are known as secondary indexes in the OP is incorrect (i.e. documentation bug) and there are more than two types of indexes: clustered, secondary, spatial, fulltext?

Sure, it could use some clarification. But it's kind of comparing apples and oranges. One might also think of spatial and fulltext indexes as secondary indexes, because they are not a clustered index (and cannot be such).
